# How to query by custom post type values in WordPress?

Tags: custom-post-type, wordpress

I have a `Custom Post Type` using the `Custom Post Type UI` plugin called `Case Studies`. I'm also using the `Custom Fields` to add a `capability` field to the `Case Studies`.

How can I query `Case Studies` where the `capability` is equal to some ID?

`$query = array('post_type' => 'case-studies','posts_per_page' => 3);`

is my query so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your key to capability, and then query value by your post ID.

```
'meta_query' => array(
  array(
    'key' => 'capability',
    'value' => $post->ID,
    'compare' => 'example'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It could be

```
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'case-studies',
    'meta_key' => 'capability',
    'meta_value' => 10, // some ID
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $query );
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    // echo here
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
```